# fourier-transform: where is my mistake?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to do a fourier-transform of the function 
$$\psi(x,t=0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}(2\pi)^{1/4}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}}e^{ik_0x}$$

My calculation is

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x,t=0)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}(2\pi)^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(k_0-k)x-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}}dx$$

Now I know that the following holds

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx}dx=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{2a}}$$

which leads me to the fourier-transform of my function

$$\psi(x,t=0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma}(2\pi)^{1/4}}\sqrt{4\pi\sigma^2}e^{-(k_0-k)^2\sigma^2}=\pi^{1/4}\cdot 2^{3/4}\sqrt{\sigma}e^{-(k_0-k)^2\sigma^2}$$

but my book says the solution is $$\psi(x,t=0)=\pi^{1/4}\cdot 2^{3/4}e^{-(k_0-k)^2\sigma^2}$$ which leaves me confused. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think the book is wrong.  Maybe the $\sqrt\sigma$ in the denominator of the statement of the problem should be $\sigma$.

Comment: okay, that possibility I have not considered so far, but I guess you're right since I keep getting the same result after countless calculations.